# Un nuevo artículo en el Centro de Ayuda sobre traducciones

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda, traducciones-de-contenido

A lot of thanks to [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) for translation and to [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui), [@blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7176/blonfu) for edits.

---

Anteriormente hubo dos publicaciones sobre si traducir preguntas de Stack Overflow en inglés y entiendo que la comunidad está de acuerdo en que se haga.  Si la comunidad piensa que traducir las preguntas del inglés merece la pena, sería genial añadir al Centro de Ayuda un artículo sobre ello.  Dejo abajo una propuesta de la versión inicial del artículo. Por favor, ¡sentíos libres de hacer cambios y aclaraciones!

---

> ## ¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?
>
> **¡Por supuesto!**
>
> Si encuentras una pregunta útil en uno de los sitios de la red Stack Exchange ( por ejemplo en Stack Overflow en inglés), que **no ha sido ya publicada** en Stack Overflow en español y la pregunta es válida según lo descrito en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic), por favor, tradúce la pregunta y la/s respuesta/s al español y publícala en el sitio. [Nuestro manifiesto](/help/manifesto):
>
> > Crear un mundo en el que, para cualquier consulta a un motor de búsqueda, los resultados de la búsqueda muestren el enlace a una respuesta detallada en español.
>
> Las traducciones aumentan el conocimiento disponible en español y ayudan a miles de compañeros a entender y resolver problemas actualmente limitados por el idioma.
>
> #### ¿Qué debo tener en cuenta al traducir?
>
> - *El autor de las traducciones recibe reputación*. Preguntas traducidas son equivalentes a [las respuestas en preguntas propias](/help/self-answer). Por favor, usa este sistema para contribuir al conocimiento en español en el sitio.
> - *[No olvides citar la fuente y la publicación original](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)*. Agradece al autor original de las publicaciones añadiendo un enlace a su publicación en la traducción.
> - *Ten en cuenta tu campo de conocimientos*. Lo mejor sería traducir aquellas preguntas de las que ya tienes un conocimiento en el tema. En este caso, las traducciones contendrán vocabulario propio del campo tratado y ayudará  a la hora de traducir futuras respuestas, ediciones sugeridas y comentarios.
> - *Calidad por encima de cantidad*. Traducciones pobres en calidad, como traducciones automáticas, como cualquier otra publicación pueden ser cerradas y eliminadas por la comunidad.
> - *Improvisa*. Al traducir, puedes juntar varias respuestas en una sola y así crear una respuesta canónica.

Comment: Me parece que existen mejores términos que "**Improvisa**" para "Al traducir, puedes juntar varias respuestas en una sola y así crear una respuesta canónica". Los primeros que me vienen a la mente son **Integra**, Adapta.

Comment: @Rubén Si son raros los términos porque no los cambias?

Comment: ¿Son válidas esas preguntas de hace 10 años que tienen unas pocas palabras y muchos puntos o serían demasiado amplias?

Comment: Hi @ArtEze! Sorry for using English. It's up to the community. The main point is to build a knowledge base in Spanish. If there is a short question with a lot of upvotes which is still relevant and important from the community's point of view why not to translate it?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Thanks, it's true, I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of thanks to [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) and [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) for the translation!

---

Muchas gracias a todos los que participaron en las discusiones sobre la traducción de preguntas del inglés al idioma español. Creo que es un tema muy importante.

Basándome en los comentarios recibidos, he añadido un nuevo artículo del Centro de Ayuda: [¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)

Si tenéis alguna pregunta o sugerencia, no dudéis en comentar aquí o en la sala de chat [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal).